# Why, in the result of this object type intersection, is the type of the `constructor` property intersected with `Function`?

Tags: typescript, types, intersection, object-type

If I perform this type intersection:

```ts
{ constructor: 'FooConstructor', value1: boolean } & { value2: number };
```

The resulting type is this:

```ts
{ constructor: 'FooConstructor' & Function, value1: boolean, value2: number };
```

([Playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgQrAFzwDeiqmMArmBkjCQOQBieAwpRjXQ0wDTwAblAjUQARhIAjPBBBQU8AL7wAZGWGjxAJhIpqAW2kgYKgNwAoSwHob8ACoALAJZp4aJ0moRg8UzAMAITwAAbI6Ny09DChHl4+fgD6KEgYSfAm8C4oGKZo4Hl+AO4uGE5hLNQodC6ooUGWEZj+AB4ADoUAojCBjJrNUbz9rBxcPDFM6vBVNRh1KIIiYpIycgqLWit68AbGpirwALw4eIQw5kA))

Why is the type of the resulting `constructor` property intersected with `Function`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because:

- The type `{ constructor: 'FooConstructor', value1: boolean } & { value2: number }` is a subtype of `object`, because every object type is.
- The type `object['constructor']` is `Function`.

And that's because objects in Javascript *do* have a property named `constructor` which refers to the function used to construct them:

```js
> let obj = {};
> obj.constructor
ƒ Object() { [native code] }
```

I suggest using a property name like `constructor_` or `constructorName` instead, since `constructor` is meant to refer to an actual constructor.